# My vue cli shopping cart is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm building a shopping cart in vue cli but is not working. I don't see the expected results. I'm just trying to add a product to cart but nothing happens and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Please help me with some ideas.

This is my code in app.vue:

```
<mostrar-productos :listaPlantas="listaPlantas"
    @restar-products="restProd">
</mostrar-productos>


<script>

export default {
    name: 'App',
    data() {
        return {
            listaPlantas: [
                { id: "flor", name: "flores", qty: 0, stock: 5, price: 1000 },
                { id: "cact", name: "cactus", qty: 0, stock: 3, price: 2000 },
                { id: "arbol", name: "árboles", qty: 0, stock: 6, price: 7000 },
            ],
        };
    },
    methods:{
        restProd(addProduct){
            for(let item of this.listaPlantas){
                if(item.name== addProduct.name){
                    console.log(item.stock +=1);
                    item.stock +=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


</script>
```

This is my code in my component named MostrarProductos.vue:

```
       <div v-for="item in listaPlantas" :key="item.id" v:bind="listaPlantas">
         <ul>
           <li>
              {{ item.name }}
              {{ item.stock }}
              {{ item.price }}
             <button @click="restarProducto()">Agregar</button>
           </li>
          </ul> 
       </div>

      <script>
         export default {
            emits: ['restar-products'],
            props: {
                 listaPlantas: {
                 type: Array,
                 },
                 id:{
                 type: String,
                 }
            },
           methods:{
              restarProducto(item){
                let addItem = {
                stock: this.stock,
                name: this.name, 
              },
              this.$emit("restar-products", addItem);
           }
         }
       } 
      </script>
```

Comment: What does the browser console say? Any errors?

Comment: No errors at all

Comment: No errors, no help. "but is not working" is not valid "problem" who anyone is able to help you with. We dont have a magic glas sphere where your problem/issue is popping up. Edit your question with more details, what the issue is. I highly doubt that this is a issue with "vue-cli". Where is the part of "adding"?! Provide at least a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Refrain from making comments if you don't have anything useful to say.